# Manually change css of a page I don't own

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working on a mobile app with HTML5 and when I want to visualize it on a phone I go to this website http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

but when I enter the url of my app, this website shows it at the left. I know I can change the css of through the devtools or javascript console but I couldn't center the view of my app. can someone help me ?

they are using even jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the console after you load your mobile app, and type this

```
$("#viewport").css("margin-left",300);
```

you can change 300 depending on your screen to center the view, and you can remove that footer beneath the view with this

```
$("#viewport-footer").remove();
```